# How do I make a form button pop up a dialog for confirmation in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I have a form and when the user hits submit, I want to be able to display a message "Are you sure you want to do this"? and if they hit yes, I want it to be submitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code in your view

```
 echo $this->Form->create('FormName',array(
                'type'=>'file','onsubmit'=>'return confirm("are you sure?");')
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

automatically in cake there is not direct solution for a button as it is for a link :S though you may do it with javascript.

Here is a code for it using jquery for the events asuming your button id is "submit"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
          return confirm('You sure you want to continue?');
    });
});
```

With this you are done, just load this js into your page and change it to please your needs :D hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In case using cakePHP 4.4, you can use as following:

```
$this->Form->postLink(
                        '<i class="bi-trash bi-md"></i> Delete',
                        ['action' => 'delete', $id],
                        ['method' => 'delete', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure?', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'escape' => false]
                    )
```

A delete button will be rendered in html, and it is clicked a confirm popup will display.